# Naviagation Page is not setting BarBackgroundColor in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Below is the code for XAML for customNavigation in Xamarin. The bar color is not set but Bar text color is set. And this is only happening in Android, iOS works fine.

```
<NavigationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DSXMobile.Views.CustomNavigationView"
             BarBackgroundColor="Red"
             BarTextColor="Black">
</NavigationPage>
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue,

From Xamarin forums https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88569/barbackgroundcolor-refusing-to-get-set-on-android-but-bartextcolor-is-fine

"If you are using FormsAppCompatActivity

This is a bug in XF if you're using the FormsAppCompatActivity.

The workaround is to set android:background in your applications' layout file used for FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource.

Set this value to anything, example: android:background="#00000000"

Then XF will style it with whatever colour is in your XAML style later.

Really dumb bug, hope it gets sorted soon."

Another reference:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37657/how-to-change-the-nav-bar-background-color-on-android

Two annoying Custom Renderer Solutions:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17811/tabbedpage-tabbar-background-color-tint

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59828/change-barbackgroundcolor-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer says its a bug but i don't know if it should be called a bug because android is doing what it does picking the theme that you have assigned to its activity in your styles.xml now what you can do is make that same change in your styles.xml my theme something like this :

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <resources>
      <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
       </style>

       <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" 

    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
       <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item>
       </style>

     <style name="MyTheme.Base" 
 parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#003399</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#003399</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#003399</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#012348</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    </resources>
```

Changing the colors in here will change it there aswell for eg ColorPrimary is your toolbar color